# Determine whether there’s more than one word in a string

Tags: python, string, split

For example:

```
line = 'how are you?'

if line == [has more than one word]: line.split()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Get the value of `line.split()` first, then check the `len()` of the resulting list.

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
line = 'how are you?'

if len(line.split()) > 1: # has more than 1 word
```

Comment: This answer is best because it handles any kind of whitespace... it would also produce a correct result for `"how\tare\tyou"`, which separates the words with tabs, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the line.split() seems more pythonic, but if that was going to be an expensive operation, this might be faster:

```
if ' ' in 'how are you?': line.split()
```

Comment: It's 6x faster than `line.count(' ')` and 9x faster than `if len(line.split())` in 2.7

Comment: you can have a space after a word and before a single word

Comment: Ooh good point! @Padraic. Depending on how you're getting the input, a lstrip and/or an rstrip could be prudent.

Answer (score 2):

```
line.strip().count(' ') > 0 # finds at least one separator after removing the spaces at the left and the right of the actual string
```

or if you really want speed

```
line.strip().find(' ') != -1 # not finding the ' ' character in the string
```

Comment: `" foo " == True` `"foo  " == True`

Comment: `.lstrip().rstrip()` is just `.strip()`, and `' ' in line.strip()` is easier.